# MS Access: "Cannot open any more databases."

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error

The Access error, "Cannot open any more databases.", has been discussed several times on StackOverflow[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579186/ms-access-2010-cannot-open-any-more-databases), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39898729/ms-access-occassional-cannot-open-any-more-databases-error), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519628/getting-error-3048-cannot-open-any-more-databases), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68991109/access-error-3048-cannot-open-any-more-databases-when-attempting-docmd-transfe)]. There's also an interesting [discussion of the error](https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/208627-cannot-open-any-more-databases) on Bytes.com, in which Allen Brown and David Fenton weigh in on what can cause the error and argue about whether the limit behind it is about connections or table handles. None of the causes or solutions in those places apply to my situation, as far as I can tell.

I've got a complex database that was working well, but then started throwing this error. I've boiled down the VBA code and data structure to the following bare bones:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function TestFunction(ID_test_1 As Integer, nID_test_2 As Integer) As Variant

Dim oCurDb_Ftn As DAO.Database, oTestData As DAO.Recordset, sSQL As String, vTestCode As Variant

Set oCurDb_Ftn = CurrentDb()
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM t_test_2 WHERE ID_test_2 = " & nID_test_2 & ";"
Set oTestData = oCurDb_Ftn.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
vTestCode = oTestData![bValue]

oTestData.Close
Set oTestData = Nothing
Set oCurDb_Ftn = Nothing

TestFunction = vTestCode

End Function    ' TestFunction
```

[image]

The numbers in the tables are arbitrary. The fields `ID_test_n` are primary keys. The code above is the entire contents of `TestModule`. The query `TestQuery` is:

```
SELECT t_test_1.ID_test_1, TestFunction(ID_test_1,3) AS [Test code]
FROM t_test_1;
```

When the query is opened, it at first appears to be okay. But if I scroll down through it, it throws the "cannot open any more" error:
[image]

I've discovered one way that I can get rid of the error. If I remove the first parameter of the function `TestFunction()`, so that it's definition becomes:

```
Public Function TestFunction(nID_test_2 As Integer) As Variant
...
```

and the call to it in the query becomes just:

```
TestFunction(3)
```

then I can scroll down and up through the query sheet multiple times without error. Those changes are possible because in the bare-bones code of the function, there is no reference to `ID_test_1`. But in the actual database, that parameter is passed for a reason and omitting it is not an option. Still, it is mysterious to me that whatever is causing the error does not happen if that parameter is not passed.

Can anyone see what's going on here, why I'm getting that error, and how to fix it without excluding parameters from the function?

Environment: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit, Access 2019.

Comment: I haven't reviewed your code but I followed the suggestion on this video and managed to avoid this problem with code I ran today: https://youtu.be/zPC0dhgVYeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be due to a bug in an Office update, about Jan 26, 2022.  See [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/MSAccess/comments/sicy5t/fyi_office_365_version_2201_jan_26_broke_my_app/)

Try system restore to roll back the update; or...

Go into Access, File Options, Trust center and add the local front end directory and then check the box to then add the backend data location as a trusted location.

Comment: Also, as noted in video listed in my 1st comment, be sure to check the box to include subfolders when adding locations.

Comment: @UsuallyConfused - Thank you. So now I know I'm not out of my mind. Your Reddit link led me to an MS forum, which led me to a more formal report on the problem and workarounds: https://www.devhut.net/another-access-bug-cannot-open-any-more-databases/ . I would say your second listed solution is better to try first, which I did, and it worked! After three days of pulling my hair out over this.

Comment: By the way, it seems pretty weird that trusted locations would have anything to do with counting table handles.